# When does $ f'_{n}(x) \to g(x) =1$ imply $f'(x) =1 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I considered the following:

$f_{n}(x) \in C^1(0,1)$ (class of continuously differentiable functions) and $f_{n} \to f:(0,1) \to \bf{R} $ with $f'_{n} \to g =1$. Does this imply that $f \in C^1(0,1)$ also? The convergence is pointwise.

I realized that the function sequence $f_{n}(x) = \arctan(nx)+x$ is a counterexample. However, suppose that the convergence is in $L^1$, i.e., in the mean $p$ with $p=1$. Can we now claim that $f \in C^1(0,1)$ and $f'(x) =1 $?

Comment: Are you not assuming that functions in $C^1(0,1)$ are *continuously* differentiable?

Comment: Yes I am. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: In which sense do $f_n\to f$?

Comment: The convergence is pointwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, convergence $f_n'\to 1$ in $L^1$ is enough to conclude that $f(x)=x$ up to a constant. Indeed, let $c = f(1/2) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(1/2)$. The fundamental theorem of calculus implies
$$
|f_n(x) - (x-1/2+c)| \le |f_n(1/2) - c| + \|f'_n-1\|_{L^1} \to 0
$$
Thus, $f_n(x) \to x-1/2+c$ uniformly. The function $f(x) = x-1/2+c$ is obviously in $C^1$.

More generally (if $g$ wasn't identically $1$) under the $L^1$ convergence assumption you can conclude that $f$ is an antiderivative of $g$. So, as long as $g$ is continuous, $f\in C^1$ follows.

---

*Aside*. Because I did not really understand your example with $\arctan$, I wrote up another one. With two minor modifications in the setup:

1. Let's subtract $x$ from every $f_n$, so that we have simpler condition $f_n'\to 0$ instead of $f_n'\to 1$.
2. Let's replace $(0,1)$ with $(-1,1)$ so that it's easier to create bad things insiden .

Define $f_n(x) = e^{-nx^2}$. As $n\to \infty$, this sequence converges pointwise to the discontinuous function 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad & x=0, \\ 0 \quad & x\ne 0 \end{cases} $$
Yet, the sequence of derivatives, $f'_n(x) = -2xn e^{-nx^2}$ converge to $0$ pointwise.

Comment: The $arctan(nx) + x$ is a very simple concoction (correct any mistakes if you find please). We have $f_{n}(x) = arctan(nx) + x$ so that $f'_{n}(x) = 1 + \frac{n}{1+n^2 x^2}$. It is clear that $f'_n \to 1$ pointwise. But $f_n(x)$ goes to a discontinuous function which has a jump at $0$.

Comment: Obviously, to make the interval $(0, 1)$ you can just shift   $arctan(x)+x$ by 1/2 to $arctan(x-1/2) + x-1/2$. By the way, many thanks for a second counterexample.

Comment: @Iconoclast But $f_n'(0)=1+n$ for the arctangent example, isn't it? So pointwise convergence to $1$ does not hold. My example does not have this problem, because the derivative at the "bad" point is kept the same all the time.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: On another note, (My question does not clear state this), if the convergence of the derivatives is taken in $L^1$ don't you think that your counterexample also works in that case, i.e., if $f'_n \to 1$ in $L^1$. Your derivatives go to $0$ in $L^1$, am I correct?

Comment: @Iconoclast No, $2xne^{-nx^2}$ does not tend to $0$ in  $L^1$, which you can check by integrating it from $0$ to $1$, for example.

Comment: @Iconoclast $\int_0^1 f_n'(x)\,dx = f_n(1)-f_n(0) = e^{-n} - 1 \to -1$. So, $\int_0^1 |f_n'(x)|\,dx$ does not tend to $0$.